# Add background color to text entered in textInput react native

Tags: react-native

I want to add `backgroundColor` to text entered in `textInput` in react native.

So as user type in `textInput` that background color grow as text entered.

```
<TextInput
  autoFocus
  value={newTopic}
  textAlignVertical="bottom"
  onChangeText={val => dispatch(setNewTopic(val))}
  style={{
    paddingBottom: 0,
    paddingTop: 2.5,
    paddingRight: 38,
    backgroundColor: "red",
  }}
  blurOnSubmit
  placeholder={Strings.inputs.addTopicPlaceholder}
/>
```

add `backgroundColor: "red",` change background color of whole input but I need for text only.

How can I do this in react native?

Comment: do you want to change the color of the text entered ?

Comment: @MuhammadJunaid backgroundColor.

Comment: Ciao @BeHappy. This question putted me into an infinite quest and now I don't know if show you the only thing I achieved or just destroy everything I made. Would you accept an intermediate solution? :)

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito If it works why not :)

Comment: Ok I will post it. But if you don't accept just add a comment and I will remove it in 1 second

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an exact solution to this.
You can try adding an absolute view in relative to the TextInput's parent View and modify its width based on the entered text's length.

```
class Cat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sampleText: '',
    };
  }
  onChangeText = (sampleText) => {
    this.setState({
      sampleText,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ position: 'relative' }}> // to keep the absolute view inside
          <TextInput
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(112,232,123,0.2)',
              borderWidth: 1,
            }}
            onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: 'yellow',
              zIndex: -1,
              height: '100%',
              width: this.state.sampleText.length * 7.5, //change based on fontSize
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```